# Mouse move panning

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to scroll a series of thumbnails horizontally based on the mouseX position. I can get it to scroll but it's very choppy and for some reason it's not reading my start and end numbers so it will stop scrolling. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
var thumbBounds:Object = new Object(); 
thumbBounds = thumbContainer.getBounds(this); 
thumbContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, setScrolling); 

private function setScrolling(me:MouseEvent):void         
{             
    thumbContainer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, setScrolling);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollThumbs);         
} 

private function scrollThumbs(e:Event):void         
{             
    if(mouseX <= thumbBounds.x || mouseX > thumbBounds.width || 
       mouseX < thumbBounds.y || mouseX > thumbBounds.height)
    {                 
        thumbContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, setScrolling); 
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollThumbs);             
    } 

    if(thumbContainer.x >= 0)             
    {                 
        thumbContainer.x = 0;             
    }             

    if(thumbContainer.x <= -842)            
    {                 
        thumbContainer.x = -842;            
    }             

    var xdist:Number = new Number();             
    xdist = mouseX - 382;             
    thumbContainer.x += Math.round(-xdist / 10);         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error I see immediately is:

```
if(mouseX <= thumbBounds.x || mouseX > thumbBounds.width || 
   mouseX < thumbBounds.y || mouseX > thumbBounds.height)
```

Shouldn't you be checking the `mouseY` agains the `thumbBounds.y` and `thumbBounds.height`?

As for the choppyness, that could be related to the framerate of the movie, the size and the number of the images. It also depends on the magnitude of your `xdist` value. I'd try and use interpolation (tweening) some how. Calculate the end destination of the container and animate it towards there using [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) or [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).

e.g.

```
TweenLite.to(thumbContainer.x, 0.5, { x: thumbContainer.x + Math.round(-xdist / 10) });
```

This will cause the movement between the `thumbcontainer` current position and the new position will happen smoothly over half a second (instead of immediately).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give your suggestions a try.